# Connecting to KEPSERVER using C# application(windows form) & opccomrcw.dll

Tags: c#, plc, opc, siemens, kepserverex

I have a license to KEPSERVER EX5 and it is connected to Siemen S7 PLC. Is there anyway tutorial to read data being displayed on Kepserver using C# application and & opccomrcw.dll or using any other free plug-in? I know there is plug in from Kepserver that seems to be able to connect database using odbc but my boss isn't buying the license. Yes, it is company asset and previous developer used C# windows form and & opccomrcw.dll to make connection to kepserver to read plc data. Unfortunately, it was done by 3rd party developer and we don't have full source code. I do not really care it is through opccomrcw.dll. I just need to be able to read data displayed on kepserver on c# windows form application. So far, I can't find any tutorial guide on this. Help.

Answer (score -1):

There is an extensive C# solution on the OPC Foundation's github:

https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/

Or if you are just using DA, there are many samples online of using the OpcDaAuto DLL for simple OPC client access to tag data.